# Express app.all declaring req/res vs not

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In express, everything else held constant, is there a difference between:

```
app.all('/', mongoProxy(config.mongo.dbUrl, config.mongo.apiKey));
```

and

```
app.all('/', function (req, res) {
  mongoProxy(config.mongo.dbUrl, config.mongo.apiKey);
 });
```

The former is able to return the return value from `mongoProxy` while the latter is not, where `mongoProxy` looks something like this:

```
module.exports = function(basePath, apiKey) {

  basePath = url.parse(basePath);

  // Map the request url to the mongolab url
  // @Returns a parsed Url object
  var mapUrl = module.exports.mapUrl = function(reqUrlString) {
    //use the basePath to Parse the URL
    return newUrl;
  };

  var mapRequest = module.exports.mapRequest = function(req) {
    var newReq = mapUrl(req.url);
    // Make a new request and return it..
    return newReq;
  };

  var proxy = function(req, res, next) {
    try {
      var options = mapRequest(req);
      // Create the request to the db
      var dbReq = https.request(options, function(dbRes) {
         // Save result 
        });
          // { send result }
          res.send(data);
          res.end();
        });
      });
      // send request 
      dbReq.end(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    } catch (error) {
      //..
    }
  };
  return proxy;
};
```

The documentation is not clear on explaining the conceptual difference between the two; in the examples I've seen, the former function

```
app.all('/', mongoProxy(config.mongo.dbUrl, config.mongo.apiKey));
```

is able to access the req and res object without having it actually passed in as done in the latter, `function (req, res)`.

What is the difference between the two, and is one preferable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tl;dr

Yes, there is a difference: the first will work, whereas the second will hang (you don't invoke the anonymous function returned by `mongoProxy`). The first is preferable because it is more idiomatic to express (you're using middleware).

---

First, note how in `mongoProxy`, you `return proxy`, an anonymous function:

```
module.exports = function(basePath, apiKey) {
  /* snip */
  var proxy = function(req, res, next) { // <-- here
  /* snip */
  };
  return proxy;    // <-- and here
};
```

Let's break it down:

```
var proxy = mongoProxy(config.mongo.dbUrl, config.mongo.apiKey)
// proxy is an anonymous function which accepts: (req, res, next)

app.all('/', proxy);
// express will use proxy as the callback (middleware), which means this is the same as:
app.all('/', function (req, res, next) {
    proxy(req, res, next)
})
```

Let's rewrite the second example—which should make clear why it *doesn't* work:

```
var proxy = mongoProxy(config.mongo.dbUrl, config.mongo.apiKey)
app.all('/', function (req, res) {
    proxy    // nothing happens because you don't invoke the function
});
```

If you want to use the second example, you could invoke `proxy` with `proxy(req, res, next)`, but this is not idiomatic (in general and especially for express). Express is all about middleware, so use the first example.

Here's another example, which uses a closure (much like your `mongoProxy` function):

```
function getPermissionLevelMiddleware (level) {
    // returns an anonymous function which verifies users based on `level`
    return function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated() && req.user.permission.level > level)
            return next()
        return res.redirect('/no/permission')
    }
}

var isAdmin = getPermissionLevelMiddleware(9000)
// `isAdmin` only allows users with more than 9000 `user.permission.level`
var isPleb = getPermissionLevelMiddleware(1)
// `isPleb` allows users with more than 1 `user.permission.level`

app.get('/admin', isAdmin, function (req, res) {
    res.render('admin.jade')
})
```

Comment: Beautifully explained and very helpful. Much appreciated! :-)

Comment: @nikkwong glad I was able to help. Your `mongoProxy` function is a good example of how to use a closure in JavaScript to remember a variable's state.

Comment: This is truly great—explains a bunch of important concepts all at the same time. Can't upvote enough! Thank you.

Comment: @nikkwong just found a **big** mistake (typo) in my answer. The *first* case is preferable, **not** the second.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the first one will return result because **req** and **res** objects are accessible to it, where as second case you need to send **req** and **res** in the **method params** of **mongoProxy**. If you won't send, **req and res** won't be accessible to it. So, for second scenario to work, the **method signature** need to be changed to :

```
module.exports = function(basePath, apiKey, req, res) {
```

I have done